# Preparing the DOM for a Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, html, dom, single-page-application

What I am trying to achieve appears to be simple. I am assuming that all content visible on a page, is a child or grandchild of the  tag of a HTML page? This text for example must be related to Body.

And this is a `tree` structure basically starting (visually) with Body.

I want to make a Single Page Application with JavaScript. But I need to prepare the DOM and here is where I struggle.

How do I set up the body of the page so that:

- There is no scroll bars
- The Body is always filling the entire content area of the browser (if it does not already)
- Break out of CSS box model (appendChild 10 times stacks those elements, not flows them)
- Any children Divs from Body, also by default break out of the CSS box model too.

I have searched for each step individually but I do not use JQuery, and to be honest, I would prefer to get rid of CSS too all but for the most basic of tasks. I would just like to have a known viewable region and be responsible for its positioning, sizing and content with JS.

Or. If you are similar with Flash.  I want to treat the Body as my Stage and use it like a Display List with NO_SCALE enabled. Meaning that when you resize, that should "invalidate" the layout (that is upto me as the developer).

I am not the first person in the world to ask for this. So if you could even point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: So you want to fill the whole view-port and clip/scroll/resize all children? No scrollbars visible on right and bottom? What elements do you want to place on the page? Top-Menu-bar? left-navigation? Maybe [jquery layout plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) might help you. It's not trivial, especially not if you have to support IE < 10.

Comment: Kind of yeah! Lets say for example, I create a HTMLDivElement, this contains a HTMLCanvasElement and a HTMLTextElement.  I want exclusive control of the layout of these elements within the DIV and in turn, control of that div on the Body. This is for modern browsers only so I do not care about compatibility with older browsers as my intention is to experiment.

I am looking to avoid JQuery as I feel it hides implementation and the purpose of this is to learn modern JS (From a AS3 background).

Comment: In the very worse case situation, the very minimum I want is a full screen Canvas element (probably WebGL mostly). When the page resizes, I will capture the event, and "invalidate()" my JS application which in turn lays out the "canvas children".  But getting an answer on how to "have a full screen anything" seems at best hacked together. I feel I am missing something such as an alternative rendering mode which stacks instead of flows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CSS based solution to the fullest, then move on with Javascript. Following would give you pretty much what you want

- There is no scroll bars
- The Body is always filling the entire content area of the browser (if it does not already)

  `html, body {
      margin : 0px
      padding : 0px;
      border : 0px;
      overflow : hidden; 
      position : absolute;
      left : 0px;
      top : 0px;
   }`
- Break out of CSS box model (appendChild 10 times stacks those elements, not flows them)
- Any children Divs from Body, also by default break out of the CSS box model too.

  put this first

  `* {
      position : absolute;
   }`

Comment: Thanks Rahul, this seems to be exactly what I was after. I will try it now.

Comment: This basically resets the default values of the html tags (body,etc). So you are getting a freedom to position, animate the elements in the viewable area using javascript. Good luck!! If this works out, please upvote too :P

Comment: Would the "true" width and height of this page be `document.body.innerWidth" and "document.body.innerHeight"?

Comment: For page dimension, I would suggest you to use "document.body.offsetWidth" and "document.body.offsetHeight". It is always advisable to check in multiple browsers to find any inconsistency. Also you can set width : 100% , height : 100% in the `html, body` style.